# overwrite wordpress gallery with custom gallery shortcode

Tags: php, plugin-development, shortcode, media-library, media-modal

I want to overwrite the default WordPress gallery shortcode with a custom one. This because I need to add a field that will contain an url for each image I want to add inside a gallery. I'm not sure how to proceed, but for now I wrote this prototype of the code I want to use for the shortcode, I'm not sure how to proceed for the custom link field. Also I need to understand how to open the media library modal to multiselect the images and add to the shortcode `id` param, the various ids of the images and their relative links. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

```
function custom_gallery( $atts ){
  extract(shortcode_atts('id' => '','links' => '')); 
  // here I need to implement code for link and image selection
}
add_shortcode( 'gallery', 'custom_gallery');
```

Answer (score 1):

At the top of the [Gallery Shortcode Callback](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/gallery_shortcode/) is a filter hook: [post_gallery](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_gallery/)

If any non-empty / non-null output is returned from this filter the shortcode will use that output instead of the default generation. You can copy the source of the [Gallery Shortcode Callabck](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/gallery_shortcode/) and modify it as you see fit.

The below is a filter hook, using the entire code of the gallery callback with the `post_gallery` filter hook removed to prevent any infinite looping.

```
/**
 * Custom Gallery Function for custom output
 * 
 * @param string $output   The gallery output. Default empty.
 * @param array  $attr     Attributes of the gallery shortcode.
 * @param int    $instance Unique numeric ID of this gallery shortcode instance.
 *
 * @return String $output
 */
function my_custom_gallery( $output, $attr, $instance ) {

    $post = get_post();
    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;
    if ( ! empty( $attr['ids'] ) ) {
            // 'ids' is explicitly ordered, unless you specify otherwise.
            if ( empty( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
                    $attr['orderby'] = 'post__in';
            }
            $attr['include'] = $attr['ids'];
    }

    $html5 = current_theme_supports( 'html5', 'gallery' );
    $atts  = shortcode_atts(
            array(
                    'order'      => 'ASC',
                    'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
                    'id'         => $post ? $post->ID : 0,
                    'itemtag'    => $html5 ? 'figure' : 'dl',
                    'icontag'    => $html5 ? 'div' : 'dt',
                    'captiontag' => $html5 ? 'figcaption' : 'dd',
                    'columns'    => 3,
                    'size'       => 'thumbnail',
                    'include'    => '',
                    'exclude'    => '',
                    'link'       => '',
            ),
            $attr,
            'gallery'
    );
    $id = intval( $atts['id'] );
    if ( ! empty( $atts['include'] ) ) {
            $_attachments = get_posts(
                    array(
                            'include'        => $atts['include'],
                            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                            'order'          => $atts['order'],
                            'orderby'        => $atts['orderby'],
                    )
            );
            $attachments = array();
            foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
                    $attachments[ $val->ID ] = $_attachments[ $key ];
            }
    } elseif ( ! empty( $atts['exclude'] ) ) {
            $attachments = get_children(
                    array(
                            'post_parent'    => $id,
                            'exclude'        => $atts['exclude'],
                            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                            'order'          => $atts['order'],
                            'orderby'        => $atts['orderby'],
                    )
            );
    } else {
            $attachments = get_children(
                    array(
                            'post_parent'    => $id,
                            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                            'order'          => $atts['order'],
                            'orderby'        => $atts['orderby'],
                    )
            );
    }
    if ( empty( $attachments ) ) {
            return '';
    }
    if ( is_feed() ) {
            $output = "\n";
            foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment ) {
                    $output .= wp_get_attachment_link( $att_id, $atts['size'], true ) . "\n";
            }
            return $output;
    }
    $itemtag    = tag_escape( $atts['itemtag'] );
    $captiontag = tag_escape( $atts['captiontag'] );
    $icontag    = tag_escape( $atts['icontag'] );
    $valid_tags = wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' );
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $itemtag ] ) ) {
            $itemtag = 'dl';
    }
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $captiontag ] ) ) {
            $captiontag = 'dd';
    }
    if ( ! isset( $valid_tags[ $icontag ] ) ) {
            $icontag = 'dt';
    }
    $columns   = intval( $atts['columns'] );
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor( 100 / $columns ) : 100;
    $float     = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';
    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";
    $gallery_style = '';
    /**
     * Filters whether to print default gallery styles.
     *
     * @since 3.1.0
     *
     * @param bool $print Whether to print default gallery styles.
     *                    Defaults to false if the theme supports HTML5 galleries.
     *                    Otherwise, defaults to true.
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', ! $html5 ) ) {
            $gallery_style = "
            <style type='text/css'>
                    #{$selector} {
                            margin: auto;
                    }
                    #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                            float: {$float};
                            margin-top: 10px;
                            text-align: center;
                            width: {$itemwidth}%;
                    }
                    #{$selector} img {
                            border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
                    }
                    #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                            margin-left: 0;
                    }
                    /* see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php */
            </style>\n\t\t";
    }
    $size_class  = sanitize_html_class( $atts['size'] );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
    /**
     * Filters the default gallery shortcode CSS styles.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param string $gallery_style Default CSS styles and opening HTML div container
     *                              for the gallery shortcode output.
     */
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . $gallery_div );
    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
            $attr = ( trim( $attachment->post_excerpt ) ) ? array( 'aria-describedby' => "$selector-$id" ) : '';
            if ( ! empty( $atts['link'] ) && 'file' === $atts['link'] ) {
                    $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $atts['size'], false, false, false, $attr );
            } elseif ( ! empty( $atts['link'] ) && 'none' === $atts['link'] ) {
                    $image_output = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $atts['size'], false, $attr );
            } else {
                    $image_output = wp_get_attachment_link( $id, $atts['size'], true, false, false, $attr );
            }
            $image_meta = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id );
            $orientation = '';
            if ( isset( $image_meta['height'], $image_meta['width'] ) ) {
                    $orientation = ( $image_meta['height'] > $image_meta['width'] ) ? 'portrait' : 'landscape';
            }
            $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
            $output .= "
                    <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon {$orientation}'>
                            $image_output
                    </{$icontag}>";
            if ( $captiontag && trim( $attachment->post_excerpt ) ) {
                    $output .= "
                            <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='$selector-$id'>
                            " . wptexturize( $attachment->post_excerpt ) . "
                            </{$captiontag}>";
            }
            $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
            if ( ! $html5 && $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 ) {
                    $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
            }
    }
    if ( ! $html5 && $columns > 0 && $i % $columns !== 0 ) {
            $output .= "
                    <br style='clear: both' />";
    }
    $output .= "
            </div>\n";
            return $output;

}
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'my_custom_gallery', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: This will also give me the ability to add an input text to give each image an unique link?

Comment: Yes, this is in the loop so you have access to the `global $post` and inside the function the `$_attachments` foreach is where you can get the attachment.

Comment: but how I pass the links, I want to add them using comma separated string in atts array, but with many links I don't think this is the better solution?

Comment: You should add post meta for the images for these links. These should be per image and is a separate question. While in the function, foreach of attachments, you can call get_post_meta()

Comment: ok, I will do some research, maybe post meta can be enough for my scope. if you provide an example link I will appreciate it.